# Box 2d: gravity and collisions

Tags: javascript, box2dweb

I'm using box2dweb 2.1a3 and a problem (I want to reproduce Angry Birds):

I read a file with level and when box2d body (#1) collides with other thing (#2) I want to destroy first body(#1). But when I will put b2d bony on another b2d body these sometimes collides (level did pixel perfect).

And of course I can post some parts of my code.

Comment: Some code would definitely be helpful. Better yet, setup a demo of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I will recreate it in jsfiddle.net and edit my post.